# Как пишется ви идеальная пара

Tags: орфография

как пишется "вы идеальная пара"?

Answer (score 3):

> Как пишется ви идеальная пара

Через "Ы". :-) *"Вы"*

И с тире.

**Вы ― идеальная пара.**

Comment: Тире не обязательно. Ведь подлежащее - местоимение.